# While working in Powershell, how do I pause between list items?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have been working on this for a while and I cannot find this utilization anywhere.  I am using a powershell array and the foreach statement:
`@('program 1','program 2','program 3').foreach{winget show $_ -args}`

I then want to have a pause between each one so I added `;sleep 1`
This does not work. It pauses for 3s (based on this eg.) and then lists the items.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok.  That certainly addresses the pausing, but I wanted the functionality of ```sleep``` rather than ```timeout```. My output: ```Press enter to continue: 
Press enter to continue: 
Press enter to continue: 
Press enter to continue: 
Press enter to continue: 
Press enter to continue: 
Press enter to continue: 
Press enter to continue: ```

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't read the post closely enough! :)

Comment: `.ForEach` outputs the collection as whole it doesn't stream values hence why you see all output at once instead of each element followed by it's corresponding sleeping time

Comment: Happens something similar to this: `{ foreach($i in $args) { $i; Start-Sleep 1 }}.Invoke(0..2)`

Comment: This nets the same result. Even if I do it as ```$i = ('1','2','3');foreach($ii in $i){write-output $ii;sleep 1}``` I get the same result.  Sleeps 3 seconds and returns all of $i

Comment: @Daniel All is good.  Strangely, even with that pause the winget's show function still did not do it's thing.

Comment: your last example in comments streams each value and sleeps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it doesn't seem to respect the order, I don't know the technical reason why. You could either use a normal `ForEach-Object`

```
'program 1','program 2','program 3' | ForEach-Object {
    winget show $_
    sleep 1
}
```

or force the output to go to the console instead of being "buffered"

```
('program 1','program 2','program 3').ForEach{
    winget show $_ | Out-Host
    sleep 1
}
```

Comment: I think that this may be an issue with winget specifically.  The output is weird.  If I do ```winget show $_|select *``` the only thing I get is a list of numbers which I can only assume are length values

Comment: Yeah winget is known for some odd output behavior

Answer (score 3):

[Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73724160/45375) provides **effective solutions**.

As for an **explanation** of the behavior you saw:

The [intrinsic **`.ForEach()` *method***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) first *collects* all *success* output produced by the successive, per-input-object invocations of the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed to it, and only *after having processed all input objects* outputs the collected results to the pipeline, i.e. the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), in the form of a [`[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection-1) instance.

In other words:

- Unlike its cmdlet counterpart, the **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet***, the `.ForEach()` *method* does *not* emit output produced in its script block *instantly* to the pipeline.
- As with any method, success output is only sent to the pipeline *when the method returns*.

  - Note that non-PowerShell .NET methods only ever produce *success* output (which is their *return value*) and only ever communicate failure via *exceptions*, which become *statement-terminating* PowerShell errors.

By contrast, the following *do* take *instant* effect inside a `.ForEach()` call's script block:

- Suspending execution temporarily, such as via a [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep)
- Forcing instant *display* (host) output, such as via [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) or [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host).

  - Note that to-host output with `Out-Host` prevents capturing the output altogether, whereas `Write-Host` output, in PowerShell v5+, can only be captured via the *information* output stream (number `6`).
- Writing to an output stream *other* than the *success* output stream, such as via `Write-Error`, `Write-Warning` or `Write-Verbose -Verbose`.

Alternatively, you may use the **[`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement***, which, like the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, also instantly emits output to the success output stream:

```
# Stand-alone foreach statement: emits each number right away.
foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i; pause }

# In a pipeline, you must call it via & { ... } or . { ... }
# to get streaming behavior.
# $(...), the subexpression operator would NOT stream, 
# i.e. it would act like the .ForEach() method.
& { foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i; pause } } | Write-Output
```

Comment: Gents, I have success. With a little variation on the ideas provided the problem has been solved. This is my inline version ```('XPDP273C0XHQH2','Nlitesoft.NTLite','JRSoftware.InnoSetup').ForEach{cls;$a = winget show $_;write-host $a.Item(1); sleep 1}``` @mklement0 Absolutely understand this now, voted up your response, but as you said at the outset Doug's answer was fantastic.  I am not sure why it worked differently before, but upon the above code it clears the screen, loads just the information that I want (Yay! learned how the .Item() part worked!), and sleeps for 1 second. Thank you both!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @JoeyHarlequin; my pleasure. Note that the simpler alternative to `$a.Item(1)` is `$a[1]`, i.e., the index syntax that is usually used with arrays.

Comment: copy that! I have always used the [x], but I keep getting yelled at  (by ISE formatting tools) for using aliases and short-cuts.  What a world we live in that humans are recoding to make the Machine happy! lol  Thanks again for all the help!